# Feeding content of an X-Window to a virtual camera

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, gstreamer, xvfb, v4l2loopback

I want to feed a virtual webcam device from an application window (under Linux/Xorg). I have so far just maximised the window and then used `ffmpeg` to grab the whole screen like this:

```
ffmpeg \
    -f x11grab -framerate 15 -video_size 1280x1024 -i :0+0,0 \
    -f v4l2 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p /dev/video6
```

where `/dev/video6` is my v4l2loopback device. This works and I can use the virtual camera in video calls in chrome. This also indicates that the v4l2loopback module is correctly loaded into the kernel.

Unfortunately, it seems that `ffmpeg` can only read the whole screen, but not an application window. `gstreamer` on the other hand can. Playing around with `gst-launch-1.0`, I was hoping that I could get away with something like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc xid=XID_OF_MY_WINDOW \
    ! "video/x-raw" \
    ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video6
```

However, that complains that `Device '/dev/video6' is not an output device.`

Given that `ffmpeg` seems happy to write to `/dev/video6` I also tried piping the gst output to ffmpeg like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc xid=XID_OF_MY_WINDOW \
    ! "video/x-raw" \
    ! filesink location=/dev/stdout \
    | ffmpeg -i - -codec copy -f v4l2 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p /dev/video6
```

But then ffmpeg complains about `Invalid data found when processing input`.

This is running inside an xvfb headless environment, so mouse interactions will not work. This rules out obs as far as I can see.

I'm adding the chrome tag, because I see that chrome in principle would also provide a virtual camera via the `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream` switch. However, it seems that this switch only supports a static file rather than a stream.

Although I don't see why, it might be relevant that the other "application window" window is simply a second browser window. So the setup is google meet (or similar) in one browser window and the virtual camera gets fed vrom a second browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding identity before v4l2sink:

```
# Better restart kernel module
sudo rmmod v4l2loopback
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback <your_options>

# Got window id from xwininfo
gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc xid=0x3000010 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2 ! identity drop-allocation=1 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video6
```

You should be able to display with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video6 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
```

No idea for your case, but for some browser on some targets/os/versions you may have to set `exclusive_caps=1` into options when loading v4l2loopback kernel module.

Also note that this may not support any source window resizing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @SeB, in order to keep the question short, I omitted how I load the v4l2loopback device. And yes, I'm reloading the module first to make sure I set `exclusive_caps=1`.

Comment: It is unclear if it worked out or not. Probably adding identity drop-allocation=true is the most important.